# ¿Cómo puedo generar modelos en Django desde una base de datos en MongoDB ?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models

Tengo una base de datos enorme en MongoDB y quiero generar los modelos de Django dinámicamente para no hacerlo a mano ( me ahorraría un montón de trabajo ).

He usado [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb) en otras ocasiones para generar los modelos, pero segun la documentación oficial de Django, solo esta disponible para bases de datos relacionales ( PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLite ).

Alguna alternativa para generar modelos con MongoDB e importarlos a mi models.py?

Comment: Pero si MongoDB se hizo sin el concepto de "modelos". Los documentos pueden contener lo que tú quieras y en la misma colección pueden tener campos diferentes. Si quieres restringir esa libertad, pues, para que usas MongoDB... mejor el ORM. Pero creo que Mongo Compass puede hacer lo que quieres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pensando un poco sobre esto, me surgen dudas sobre si es posible. Hay que tener en cuenta que un documento de `MongoDB` no tiene por qué ser "constante" ni uniforme dentro de una misma colección, con lo que la generación automática del modelo se complica.
Por ejemplo, puedes tener una colección persona con un documento similar a este:

```
    {
        nombre:"pablo", 
        telefono:666555444, 
        ciudad:"Bilbao", 
        lenguajes:["java", "kotlin"]
    }
```

Y, en la misma colección, otro documento:

```
      {
          nombre:"pedro", 
          telefono:666222333, 
          ciudad:"Madrid"
      }
```

Ambos documentos son válidos, pero un posible generador de código crearía un modelo diferente según cuál de los dos documentos analizara. Para poder obtener un modelo válido para los dos documentos tendría que analizar la colección completa (lo que sería un problema con colecciones grandes).
Supongamos que el generador lo soluciona de manera sencilla, recorriendo toda la colección y asumiendo que lenguajes puede ser una propiedad opcional.

Este otro documento también sería válido (`MongoDB` permitiría la inserción):

```
    {
        nombre:"luis", 
        telefono:666222333, 
        ciudad:["Lima","Bogotá"]
    }
```

Aquí ya la lógica de generación se complica de manera exponencial. Unos documentos tendrían una propiedad de cardinalidad=1 y otros tendrían una propiedad con N valores.
Por supuesto, esta situación se resolvería si la colección fuera homogénea, pero `MongoDB` no lo asegura.

Estos puntos ayudan a explicar por qué `inspectdb` trabaja con bases de datos relacionales y no con `MongoDB`.

Entiendo que esto puede no ser considerado una respuesta válida, aunque como comentario es ilegible, y lo borraré si es necesario.

Comment: No lo había planteado desde ese punto de vista, en realidad antes de meterlo en MongoDB hacer nada puedes definir un esquema y que valide contra el, nosotros utilizamos http://json-schema.org/ y así nos evitamos que se creen campos en los modelos innecesarios. Molaría picarse una herramienta Open Source que lo haga.